# How to insert multiple picture and display it using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm trying to append the picture that inserted, so it can be viewed.

So here the code where i can input or insert the picture :

```css
<style>

body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 1920px;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url('/img/');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.listing-container {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px #00000029;
  background-color: white;
}

.input-credential {
  color: #3C58A7;
}

.form-label {
  margin-left: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
}

.question-mark {
  color: #3C58A7;
}

.question-mark:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
}

.input-border {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #00000029;
}

.error-message {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: red;
  padding: 15px 12px;
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
}

.input-gambar {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#input-gambar-text {
  padding-left: 42.5%;
  color: #3C58A7;
}

#input-gambar-text:hover {
  color: rgb(103, 99, 99);
}

.grid {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.grid .form-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
}

.grid .form-element input {
  display: none;
}

.grid .form-element img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.grid .form-element div {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.grid .form-element div span {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#tombol-cancel-gambar {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #3C58A7;
  border-radius: 45px;
  border-color: #3C58A7;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

#tombol-cancel-gambar:hover {
  color: #3C58A7;
  background-color: white;
  border-color: #3C58A7;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="listing-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="mb-3 input-credential">
            <label class="form-label" for="myfile">
                Masukkan Gambar
                <span class="question-mark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Masukkan gambar produk anda">
                  <i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
                </span>
            </label>

            <div class="grid" id="preview_test1">
              <div class="form-element" id="test1">
                <input type="file" id="file-1" accept="image/*" multiple>
                <label for="file-1" id="file-1-preview">
                    <img src="/img/insert_gambar_penambahan_listing_barang.jpg" alt="" id="size-preview-image">
                    <div>
                        <span>+</span>
                    </div>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="preview_test2">

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

And this is the function that i used to show multiple picture that i inserted :

```js
function cancel_form_data_gambar() {
  $("#preview_test1").empty();
  $("#preview_test2").empty();

  $("#preview_test1").append('<div class="form-element" id="test1"></div>');

  $("#test1").append('<input type="file" id="file-1" accept="image/*" multiple>');
  $("#test1").append('<label for="file-1" id="file-1-preview"></label>');

  $("#file-1-preview").append('<img src="/img/insert_gambar_penambahan_listing_barang.jpg" alt="" id="size-preview-image">');
  $("#file-1-preview").append('<div> <span>+</span> </div>');

}

function readURL(input) {
  $("#preview_test1").empty();

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    $("#preview_test2").append('<img id="test_gambar' + i + '"src="#">');
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input.files && input.files[i]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#test_gambar' + i + '').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
  }

  $('#preview_test2').append('<button type="button" id="tombol-cancel-gambar" onclick="cancel_form_data_gambar()" class="btn btn-primary listing-button">Cancel Gambar</button>');

}

$("#file-1").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

the picture is suppose to be showed in id="#preview_test2" after the picture was inserted. But the picture won't appear in id="#preview_test2" and only the button appear in there. So, how can i solve it?

Comment: Welcome. Could you try to clean up a little bit the code in order to make it more readable?

Comment: @NicolasSilva sorry, i don't quite understand what you mean. But i'm already try to clean it up a little bit, is it like you mean ?